Merging Google Sheets formulas into1 to get the same Result
I am working on developing a formula that references the values in Column A and adapts its functionality based on those numbers.
For instance, if I have 25 results in Column A of Sheet1, I would like to split and use the TEXTJOIN function according to the corresponding values in Column A of Sheet2, as illustrated in the formula below.
My goal is to create a dynamic formula that operates in this manner.
Sheet1



Name




Value1


Value2


Value3


Value4


Value5


Value6


Value7


Value8


Value9


Value10


Value11


Value12


Value13


Value14


Value15


Value16


Value17


Value18


Value19


Value20


Value21


Value22


Value23


Value24


Value25



Sheet2



Number of Textjoins
Results




5
=TEXTJOIN("', '", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA("'" & Sheet1!B2:B6 & "'"))


6
=TEXTJOIN("', '", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA("'" & Sheet1!B7:B12 & "'"))


4
=TEXTJOIN("', '", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA("'" & Sheet1!B13:B16 & "'"))


5
=TEXTJOIN("', '", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA("'" & Sheet1!B17:B20 & "'"))


5
=TEXTJOIN("', '", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA("'" & Sheet1!B21:B25 & "'"))



Tried but got an error:
=TEXTJOIN("', '", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(MOD(ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)-ROW(Sheet1!B1), 5) = 0, "'" & Sheet1!B2:B & "'", "")))

Here is the final Result:



Number of Textjoins
Results




5
'Value1'', ''Value2'', ''Value3'', ''Value4'', ''Value5'


6
'Value6'', ''Value7'', ''Value8'', ''Value9'', ''Value10'', ''Value11'


4
'Value12'', ''Value13'', ''Value14'', ''Value15'


5
'Value16'', ''Value17'', ''Value18'', ''Value19', ''Value20'


5
'Value21'', ''Value22'', ''Value23'', ''Value24'', ''Value25'





Here's a generalized logic which you may adapt to your scenario:
=let(Λ,D2:D6,
 map(Λ,lambda(Σ,textjoin(", ",1,chooserows(B2:B,sequence(Σ,1,if(row(Σ)=row(Λ),1,sum(D2:offset(Σ,-1,))+1)))))))


